# Did Abbott oppose Mandela, and play rugby in South Africa during apartheid?

Tags: australia, nelson-mandela, tony-abbott, south-africa

From https://twitter.com/geeksrulz/status/515303326993235970 (53 retweets, 22 favorites)

> #heyasio Some men fight for what is right, and achieve greatness. Others care only for themselves.

[image: Text below]

> In his Uni days, Abbott referred to Mandela as a "terrorist", and implied he should be kept in jail. He then toured South Africa on a Rugby scholarship, supporting the apartheid movement, and in direct contravention of sporting bans.
>
> Brought to you by the left wing, radical, bastard Socialists at "The barricades". Look us up on Facebook.
>
> Some men fight for what is right, and achieve greatness. Others care only for themselves.

The claims are also stated in the blog post [Callow or shallow?](http://theaimn.com/callow-shallow/)

> When Abbott was President of the Students’ Representative Council at
> Sydney University, he wrote in Honi Soit that Voluntary Student
> Unionism “would finally stop all students being taxed so the SRC can
> fund groups such as International Socialists, **South African
> Terrorists**, the Spartacists, Lidcombe Health Workers Collective etc.
> which are quite irrelevant, not to say obnoxious, to student
> purposes.”

and also

> Anti-Apartheid activity was alive and well in Australia at this time.
> Many Australians supported fundraising efforts for the ANC, and
> participated in anti-Apartheid demonstrations throughout the 1960s and
> 1970s. The racially exclusive Springboks were banned from playing in
> Australia between 1974 and the end of Apartheid in 1994. In 1981, the
> Fraser government refused permission for the aircraft carrying the
> Springboks to a tour of New Zealand to refuel on Australian territory.
> **Abbott, however, accepted a rugby scholarship to tour South Africa** in
> what former Federal Labor Minister Barry Cohen described as a
> “universally acknowledged… promotional tour of Apartheid”.

Did Abbott refer to Mandela as a terrorist, and imply he should be kept in jail, and did he tour South Africa during sporting bans against apartheid South Africa?

I'm skeptical, because it sounds very similar to claims made about [David Cameron](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/was-david-cameron-linked-to-hang-nelson-mandela-posters-in-the-1980s).

Comment: Barry Cohen said "He went to South Africa on a ‘rugby scholarship’ that was universally recognised as a promotional tour of apartheid." in this 2013 article: http://www.spectator.co.uk/2013/12/where-were-you-during-apartheid/

Comment: Useful, but it's an op-ed rather than a news article.

Comment: @Ellie is Nelson-Mandela a relevant tag when the claim is about Abbott's stated views about him?

Comment: The tag is "for questions about claims based on Nelson Mandela, known for the anti-apartheid movement and as President of South Africa from 1994 to 1999". Your call whether to remove it.